# append string to attributes in xml document with xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml attribute that contains elements with id, some of those ids may occure more than once. In that case, I'd like to append _copy to all but the first element with that id.

So my xml file looks like this:

```
<elems>
<elem id="123"/>
<elem id="2832"/>
<elem id="2272"/>
<elem id="123"/>
<elem id="123"/>
</elems>
```

Desired output:

```
<elems>
<elem id="123"/>
<elem id="2832"/>
<elem id="2272"/>
<elem id="123_copy"/>
<elem id="123_copy"/>
</elems>
```

What would be the best way to do that? I was thinking something along the lines of reading the document into a variable and then checking if the id occurs more than once...

Thanks for help and tips!

Comment: Is it important to preserve the original order of the elems? If not, you could group them by id and append "_copy" to all members of a group except the first one.

Comment: no, the order doesnt matter. Ive just tried it with for-each-group. How would I append the "_copy"?

Comment: @user3813234 Please start accepting answers if they solved your problem or were helpful by ticking them right.

Comment: Sorry, was busy for a while!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ive just tried it with for-each-group. How would I append the "_copy"?

How about:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/elems">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="elem" group-by="@id">
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <elem id="{@id}{if(position() gt 1) then '_copy' else ''}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I used this version slightly adapted. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

Would this XSLT solve your problem:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="element" match="elem" use="@id"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="elem[count(key('element', @id)[1] | .) = 2]">
        <elem id="{concat(@id, '_copy')}"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: A simpler predicate that doesn't require the key would be `match="elem[preceding-sibling::elem/@id = @id]"`

Answer (score 2):

I would key the attribute itself and write the condition with the XPath 2.0 `is` operator:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:param name="marker" select="'_copy'"/>

<xsl:key name="id" match="@id" use="."/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@id[not(. is key('id', .)[1])]">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="concat(., $marker)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```